# Updating syntax highliting in NEdit for modern Fortran

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, nedit

I generally use NEdit and have a file that give highlighting for the common Fortran language.

I tried to add in some of the missing keywords like DEALLOCATE, CONTIGUOUS, etc and ailed miserably. I was using example from here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/D8JtR7m53z4

Does anyone have any good links for updated version of NEdit for F90+?

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran question, add a version if you need to distinguish, but two versions should only be used if you are asking for differences between them. Even more, you are clearly interested in Fortran 2008 (CONTIGUOUS).

Comment: According to the site rules you should rather be asking how to edit the highlighting (and possibly show your attempt too), asking for an off-site resource is considered off-topic.

Comment: Thanksfor fixing it up @VladimirF. I will try doing this again in the home machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highlights were putting in the Fortran90 before the Fortran around line 308.   Still having issues with !?OMP but working well enough, and I use CAPS for Fortran Intrinsics and CamelCase for most Variables, Subroutines and Functions...

```
! Preferences file for NEdit
!
! This file is overwritten by the "Save Defaults..." command in NEdit 
! and serves only the interactively settable options presented in the NEdit
! "Preferences" menu.  To modify other options, such as key bindings, use 
! the .Xdefaults file in your home directory (or the X resource 
! specification method appropriate to your system).  The contents of this 
! file can be moved into an X resource file, but since resources in this file
! override their corresponding X resources, either this file should be 
! deleted or individual resource lines in the file should be deleted for the
! moved lines to take effect.

nedit.fileVersion: 5.5
nedit.shellCommands: \
    spell:Alt+B:s:ED:\n\
        (cat;echo "") | spell\n\
    wc::w:ED:\n\
        wc | awk '{print $1 " lines, " $2 " words, " $3 " characters"}'\n\
    sort::o:EX:\n\
        sort\n\
    number lines::n:AW:\n\
        nl -ba\n\
    make:Alt+Z:m:W:\n\
        make\n\
    expand::p:EX:\n\
        expand\n\
    unexpand::u:EX:\n\
        unexpand\n
nedit.macroCommands: \
    Complete Word:Alt+D::: {\n\
        # Tuning parameters\n\
        ScanDistance = 200\n\
        \n\
        # Search back to a word boundary to find the word to complete\n\
        startScan = max(0, $cursor - ScanDistance)\n\
        endScan = min($text_length, $cursor + ScanDistance)\n\
        scanString = get_range(startScan, endScan)\n\
        keyEnd = $cursor-startScan\n\
        keyStart = search_string(scanString, "<", keyEnd, "backward", "regex")\n\
        if (keyStart == -1)\n\
            return\n\
        keyString = "<" substring(scanString, keyStart, keyEnd)\n\
        \n\
        # search both forward and backward from the cursor position.  Note that\n\
        # using a regex search can lead to incorrect results if any of the special\n\
        # regex characters is encountered, which is not considered a delimiter\n\
        backwardSearchResult = search_string(scanString, keyString, keyStart-1, \\\n\
                "backward", "regex")\n\
        forwardSearchResult = search_string(scanString, keyString, keyEnd, "regex")\n\
        if (backwardSearchResult == -1 && forwardSearchResult == -1) {\n\
            beep()\n\
            return\n\
        }\n\
        \n\
        # if only one direction matched, use that, otherwise use the nearest\n\
        if (backwardSearchResult == -1)\n\
            matchStart = forwardSearchResult\n\
        else if (forwardSearchResult == -1)\n\
            matchStart = backwardSearchResult\n\
        else {\n\
            if (keyStart - backwardSearchResult <= forwardSearchResult - keyEnd)\n\
                matchStart = backwardSearchResult\n\
            else\n\
                matchStart = forwardSearchResult\n\
        }\n\
        \n\
        # find the complete word\n\
        matchEnd = search_string(scanString, ">", matchStart, "regex")\n\
        completedWord = substring(scanString, matchStart, matchEnd)\n\
        \n\
        # replace it in the window\n\
        replace_range(startScan + keyStart, $cursor, completedWord)\n\
    }\n\
    Fill Sel. w/Char:::R: {\n\
        if ($selection_start == -1) {\n\
            beep()\n\
            return\n\
        }\n\
        \n\
        # Ask the user what character to fill with\n\
        fillChar = string_dialog("Fill selection with what character?", "OK", "Cancel")\n\
        if ($string_dialog_button == 2 || $string_dialog_button == 0)\n\
            return\n\
        \n\
        # Count the number of lines in the selection\n\
        nLines = 0\n\
        for (i=$selection_start; i<$selection_end; i++)\n\
            if (get_character(i) == "\\n")\n\
                nLines++\n\
        \n\
        # Create the fill text\n\
        rectangular = $selection_left != -1\n\
        line = ""\n\
        fillText = ""\n\
        if (rectangular) {\n\
            for (i=0; i<$selection_right-$selection_left; i++)\n\
            line = line fillChar\n\
            for (i=0; i<nLines; i++)\n\
            fillText = fillText line "\\n"\n\
            fillText = fillText line\n\
        } else {\n\
            if (nLines == 0) {\n\
                for (i=$selection_start; i<$selection_end; i++)\n\
                    fillText = fillText fillChar\n\
            } else {\n\
                startIndent = 0\n\
                for (i=$selection_start-1; i>=0 && get_character(i)!="\\n"; i--)\n\
                    startIndent++\n\
                for (i=0; i<$wrap_margin-startIndent; i++)\n\
                    fillText = fillText fillChar\n\
                fillText = fillText "\\n"\n\
            for (i=0; i<$wrap_margin; i++)\n\
                line = line fillChar\n\
            for (i=0; i<nLines-1; i++)\n\
                fillText = fillText line "\\n"\n\
            for (i=$selection_end-1; i>=$selection_start && get_character(i)!="\\n"; \\\n\
                    i--)\n\
                fillText = fillText fillChar\n\
            }\n\
        }\n\
        \n\
        # Replace the selection with the fill text\n\
        replace_selection(fillText)\n\
    }\n\
    Quote Mail Reply:::: {\n\
        if ($selection_start == -1)\n\
            replace_all("^.*$", "\\\\> &", "regex")\n\
        else\n\
            replace_in_selection("^.*$", "\\\\> &", "regex")\n\
    }\n\
    Unquote Mail Reply:::: {\n\
        if ($selection_start == -1)\n\
            replace_all("(^\\\\> )(.*)$", "\\\\2", "regex")\n\
        else\n\
            replace_in_selection("(^\\\\> )(.*)$", "\\\\2", "regex")\n\
    }\n\
    Comments>/* Comment */@C@C++@Java@CSS@JavaScript@Lex:::R: {\n\
        selStart = $selection_start\n\
        selEnd = $selection_end\n\
        replace_range(selStart, selEnd, "/* " get_selection() " */")\n\
        select(selStart, selEnd + 6)\n\
    }\n\
    Comments>/* Uncomment */@C@C++@Java@CSS@JavaScript@Lex:::R: {\n\
        sel = get_selection()\n\
        selStart = $selection_start\n\
        selEnd = $selection_end\n\
        commentStart = search_string(sel, "/*", 0)\n\
        if (substring(sel, commentStart + 2, commentStart + 3) == " ")\n\
            keepStart = commentStart + 3\n\
        else\n\
            keepStart = commentStart + 2\n\
        keepEnd = search_string(sel, "*/", length(sel), "backward")\n\
        commentEnd = keepEnd + 2\n\
        if (substring(sel, keepEnd - 1, keepEnd) == " ")\n\
            keepEnd = keepEnd - 1\n\
        replace_range(selStart + commentStart, selStart + commentEnd, \\\n\
            substring(sel, keepStart, keepEnd))\n\
        select(selStart, selEnd - (keepStart-commentStart) - \\\n\
            (commentEnd - keepEnd))\n\
    }\n\
    Comments>// Comment@C@C++@Java@JavaScript:::R: {\n\
        replace_in_selection("^.*$", "// &", "regex")\n\
    }\n\
    Comments>// Uncomment@C@C++@Java@JavaScript:::R: {\n\
        replace_in_selection("(^[ \\\\t]*// ?)(.*)$", "\\\\2", "regex")\n\
    }\n\
    Comments># Comment@Perl@Sh Ksh Bash@NEdit Macro@Makefile@Awk@Csh@Python@Tcl:::R: {\n\
        replace_in_selection("^.*$", "#&", "regex")\n\
    }\n\
    Comments># Uncomment@Perl@Sh Ksh Bash@NEdit Macro@Makefile@Awk@Csh@Python@Tcl:::R: {\n\
        replace_in_selection("(^[ \\\\t]*#)(.*)$", "\\\\2", "regex")\n\
    }\n\
    Comments>-- Comment@SQL:::R: {\n\
        replace_in_selection("^.*$", "--&", "regex")\n\
    }\n\
    Comments>-- Uncomment@SQL:::R: {\n\
        replace_in_selection("(^[ \\\\t]*--)(.*)$", "\\\\2", "regex")\n\
    }\n\
    Comments>! Comment@X Resources:::R: {\n\
        replace_in_selection("^.*$", "!&", "regex")\n\
    }\n\
    Comments>! Uncomment@X Resources:::R: {\n\
        replace_in_selection("(^[ \\\\t]*!)(.*)$", "\\\\2", "regex")\n\
    }\n\
    Comments>% Comment@LaTeX:::R: {\n\
                        replace_in_selection("^.*$", "%&", "regex")\n\
                        }\n\
    Comments>% Uncomment@LaTeX:::R: {\n\
                        replace_in_selection("(^[ \\\\t]*%)(.*)$", "\\\\2", "regex")\n\
                        }\n\
    Comments>Bar Comment@C:::R: {\n\
        if ($selection_left != -1) {\n\
            dialog("Selection must not be rectangular")\n\
            return\n\
        }\n\
        start = $selection_start\n\
        end = $selection_end-1\n\
        origText = get_range($selection_start, $selection_end-1)\n\
        newText = "/*\\n" replace_in_string(get_range(start, end), \\\n\
            "^", " * ", "regex") "\\n */\\n"\n\
        replace_selection(newText)\n\
        select(start, start + length(newText))\n\
    }\n\
    Comments>Bar Uncomment@C:::R: {\n\
        selStart = $selection_start\n\
        selEnd = $selection_end\n\
        newText = get_range(selStart+3, selEnd-4)\n\
        newText = replace_in_string(newText, "^ \\\\* ", "", "regex")\n\
        replace_range(selStart, selEnd, newText)\n\
        select(selStart, selStart + length(newText))\n\
    }\n\
    Make C Prototypes@C@C++:::: {\n\
        if ($selection_start == -1) {\n\
            start = 0\n\
            end = $text_length\n\
        } else {\n\
            start = $selection_start\n\
            end = $selection_end\n\
        }\n\
        string = get_range(start, end)\n\
        nDefs = 0\n\
        searchPos = 0\n\
        prototypes = ""\n\
        staticPrototypes = ""\n\
        for (;;) {\n\
            headerStart = search_string(string, \\\n\
                "^[a-zA-Z]([^;#\\"'{}=><!/]|\\n)*\\\\)[ \\t]*\\n?[ \\t]*\\\\{", \\\n\
                searchPos, "regex")\n\
            if (headerStart == -1)\n\
            break\n\
            headerEnd = search_string(string, ")", $search_end,"backward") + 1\n\
            prototype = substring(string, headerStart, headerEnd) ";\\n"\n\
            if (substring(string, headerStart, headerStart+6) == "static")\n\
            staticPrototypes = staticPrototypes prototype\n\
            else\n\
                        prototypes = prototypes prototype\n\
            searchPos = headerEnd\n\
            nDefs++\n\
        }\n\
        if (nDefs == 0) {\n\
            dialog("No function declarations found")\n\
            return\n\
        }\n\
        new()\n\
        focus_window("last")\n\
        replace_range(0, 0, prototypes staticPrototypes)\n\
    }\n
nedit.bgMenuCommands: \
    Undo:::: {\n\
        undo()\n\
    }\n\
    Redo:::: {\n\
        redo()\n\
    }\n\
    Cut:::R: {\n\
        cut_clipboard()\n\
    }\n\
    Copy:::R: {\n\
        copy_clipboard()\n\
    }\n\
    Paste:::: {\n\
        paste_clipboard()\n\
    }\n

nedit.highlightPatterns: Ada:Default\n\
    Awk:Default\n\
    C++:Default\n\
    C:Default\n\
    CSS:Default\n\
    Csh:Default\n\
    Fortran:Default\n\
    Fortran90:1:30{\n\
    Continuation:"&":::Flag::\n\
    String:"'":"'":"\\n([^ \\t]| [^ \\t]|  [^ \\t]|   [^ \\t]|    [^ \\t]|     [ \\t0]| *\\t[^1-9])":String::\n\
    Keywords:"<(LT|GT|EQ|AND|OR|ACCEPT|[Aa]ccept|ASSIGN|[Aa]ssign|AUTOMATIC|[Aa]utomatic|BACKSPACE|[Bb]ackspace|BLOCK|[Bb]lock|CALL|[Cc]all|CLOSE|[Cc]lose|COMMON|[Cc]ommon|CONTINUE|[Cc]ontinue|DATA|[Dd]ata|DECODE|[Dd]ecode|DELETE|[Dd]elete|DIMENSION|[Dd]imension|DO|[Dd]o|ELSE|[Ee]lse|ELSEIF|[Ee]lseif|ENCODE|[Ee]ncode|ENDFILE|[Ee]nd[Ff]ile|ENDFILE|[Ee]ndfile|END|[Ee]nd|ENDIF|[Ee]ndif|ENTRY|[Ee]ntry|EQUIVALENCE|[Ee]quivalence|EXIT|[Ee]xit|EXTERNAL|[Ee]xternal|FORMAT|[Ff]ormat|FUNCTION|[Ff]unction|GOTO|[Gg]oto|IF|[Ii]f|IMPLICIT|[Ii]mplicit|INCLUDE|[Ii]nclude|INQUIRE|[Ii]nquire|INTRINSIC|[Ii]ntrinsic|LOGICAL|[Ll]ogical|MAP|[Mm]ap|NONE|[Nn]one|ON|[Oo]n|OPEN|[Oo]pen|PARAMETER|[Pp]arameter|PAUSE|[Pp]ause|POINTER|[Pp]ointer|PRINT|[Pp]rint|PROGRAM|[Pp]rogram|READ|[Rr]ead|RECORD|[Rr]ecord|RETURN|[Rr]eturn|REWIND|[Rr]ewind|SAVE|[Ss]ave|STATIC|[Ss]tatic|STOP|[Ss]top|STRUCTURE|[Ss]tructure|SUBROUTINE|[Ss]ubroutine|SYSTEM|[Ss]ystem|THEN|[Tt]hen|TO|[Tt]o|TYPE|[Tt]ype|UNION|[Uu]nion|MAP|UNLOCK|[Uu]nlock|VIRTUAL|[Vv]irtual|VOLATILE|[Vv]olatile|WHILE|[Ww]hile|WRITE|[Ww]rite)>":::Keyword::D\n\
    Data Types:"<(BYTE|[Bb]yte|CHARACTER|[Cc]haracter|COMPLEX|[Cc]omplex|DOUBLE COMPLEX|[Dd]ouble *[Cc]omplex|DOUBLE *PRECISION|[Dd]ouble [Pp]recision|DOUBLE|[Dd]ouble|INTEGER|[Ii]nteger|REAL|[Rr]eal)(\\*[0-9]+)?>":::Keyword::D\n\
    F90 Keywords:"<('!'DIR'$'|DIR|OMP|DEC|EQV|NEQV|KIND|SIMD|PARALLEL OFF|PARALLEL ON|ALLOCATABLE|[Aa]llocatable|ALLOCATE|[Aa]llocate|CASE|[Cc]ase|CASE|[Cc]ase|CONTAINS|CONTIGUOUS|[Cc]ontiguous|[Cc]ontains|CYCLE|[Cc]ycle|DEALLOCATE|[Dd]eallocate|ELSEWHERE|[Ee]lsewhere|ENDWHERE|[Ee]ndwhere|INTENT|[Ii]ntent|INTERFACE|[Ii]nterface|MODULE|[Mm]odule|NAMELIST|[Nn]amelist|OPTIONAL|[Oo]ptional|PRIVATE|[Pp]rivate|PROCEDURE|[Pp]rocedure|PUBLIC|[Pp]ublic|REWRITE|[Rr]ewrite|SELECT|[Ss]elect|USE|[Uu]se|WHERE|[Ww]here)>":::Keyword::D\n\
    Numeric const:"<[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]*)?([DEde][-+]?[0-9]*)?|\\.[0-9]+([DEde][-+]?[0-9]*)?>":::Numeric Const::D\n\
    Comment:"! ":"$"::Comment::\n\
        }\n\
    Java:Default\n\
    JavaScript:Default\n\
    LaTeX:Default\n\
    Lex:Default\n\
    Makefile:Default\n\
    Matlab:Default\n\
    NEdit Macro:Default\n\
    Pascal:Default\n\
    Perl:Default\n\
    PostScript:Default\n\
    Python:Default\n\
    Regex:Default\n\
    SGML HTML:Default\n\
    SQL:Default\n\
    Sh Ksh Bash:Default\n\
    Tcl:Default\n\
    VHDL:Default\n\
    Verilog:Default\n\
    XML:Default\n\
    X Resources:Default\n\
    Yacc:Default
nedit.languageModes:    Ada:.ada .ad .ads .adb .a:::::::\n\
    Awk:.awk:::::::\n\
    C++:.cc .hh .C .H .i .cxx .hxx .cpp .c++::::::".,/\\`'!|@#%^&*()-=+{}[]"":;<>?~":\n\
    C:.c .h::::::".,/\\`'!|@#%^&*()-=+{}[]"":;<>?~":\n\
    CSS:css::Auto:None:::".,/\\`'!|@#%^&*()=+{}[]"":;<>?~":\n\
    Csh:.csh .cshrc .login .logout:"^[ \\t]*#[ \\t]*![ \\t]*/bin/csh"::::::\n\
    Fortran90:.f90 .f03 .f08 .F90 .F03 .F08:::::::\n\
    Fortran:.f .f77 .for :::::::\n\
    Java:.java:::::::\n\
    JavaScript:.js:::::::\n\
    LaTeX:.tex .sty .cls .ltx .ins:::::::\n\
    Lex:.lex:::::::\n\
    Makefile:Makefile makefile .gmk:::None:8:8::\n\
    Matlab:.m .oct .sci:::::::\n\
    NEdit Macro:.nm .neditmacro:::::::\n\
    Pascal:.pas .p .int:::::::\n\
    Perl:.pl .pm .p5 .PL:"^[ \\t]*#[ \\t]*!.*perl":Auto:None:::".,/\\\\`'!$@#%^&*()-=+{}[]"":;<>?~|":\n\
    PostScript:.ps .eps .epsf .epsi:"^%!":::::"/%(){}[]<>":\n\
    Python:.py:"^#!.*python":Auto:None:::"!""#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\\\]^`{|}~":\n\
    Regex:.reg .regex:"\\(\\?[:#=!iInN].+\\)":None:Continuous::::\n\
    SGML HTML:.sgml .sgm .html .htm:"\\<[Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll]\\>"::::::\n\
    SQL:.sql:::::::\n\
    Sh Ksh Bash:.sh .bash .ksh .profile .bashrc .bash_logout .bash_login .bash_profile:"^[ \\t]*#[ \\t]*![ \\t]*/.*bin/(bash|ksh|sh|zsh)"::::::\n\
    Tcl:.tcl .tk .itcl .itk::Smart:None::::\n\
    VHDL:.vhd .vhdl .vdl:::::::\n\
    Verilog:.v:::::::\n\
    XML:.xml .xsl .dtd:"\\<(?i\\?xml|!doctype)"::None:::"<>/=""'()+*?|":\n\
    X Resources:.Xresources .Xdefaults .nedit:"^[!#].*([Aa]pp|[Xx]).*[Dd]efaults"::::::\n\
    Yacc:.y::::::".,/\\`'!|@#%^&*()-=+{}[]"":;<>?~":
nedit.styles:   Plain:black:Plain\n\
    Comment:gray20:Italic\n\
    Keyword:black:Bold\n\
    Storage Type:brown:Bold\n\
    Storage Type1:saddle brown:Bold\n\
    String:darkGreen:Plain\n\
    String1:SeaGreen:Plain\n\
    String2:darkGreen:Bold\n\
    Preprocessor:RoyalBlue4:Plain\n\
    Preprocessor1:blue:Plain\n\
    Character Const:darkGreen:Plain\n\
    Numeric Const:darkGreen:Plain\n\
    Identifier:brown:Plain\n\
    Identifier1:RoyalBlue4:Plain\n\
    Identifier2:SteelBlue:Plain\n\
    Subroutine:brown:Plain\n\
    Subroutine1:chocolate:Plain\n\
    Ada Attributes:plum:Bold\n\
    Label:red:Italic\n\
    Flag:red:Bold\n\
    Text Comment:SteelBlue4:Italic\n\
    Text Key:VioletRed4:Bold\n\
    Text Key1:VioletRed4:Plain\n\
    Text Arg:RoyalBlue4:Bold\n\
    Text Arg1:SteelBlue4:Bold\n\
    Text Arg2:RoyalBlue4:Plain\n\
    Text Escape:gray30:Bold\n\
    LaTeX Math:darkGreen:Plain\n\
    Pointer:#660000:Bold\n\
    Regex:#009944:Bold\n\
    Warning:brown2:Italic
nedit.smartIndentInit:  C:Default\n\
    C++:Default\n\
    Python:Default\n\
    Matlab:Default
nedit.smartIndentInitCommon: Default
nedit.autoWrap: Newline
nedit.wrapMargin: 0
nedit.autoIndent: Auto
nedit.autoSave: True
nedit.openInTab: True
nedit.saveOldVersion: False
nedit.showMatching: Delimiter
nedit.matchSyntaxBased: True
nedit.highlightSyntax: True
nedit.backlightChars: False
nedit.searchDialogs: False
nedit.beepOnSearchWrap: False
nedit.retainSearchDialogs: False
nedit.searchWraps: True
nedit.stickyCaseSenseButton: True
nedit.repositionDialogs: True
nedit.autoScroll: False
nedit.appendLF: True
nedit.sortOpenPrevMenu: True
nedit.statisticsLine: False
nedit.iSearchLine: False
nedit.sortTabs: False
nedit.tabBar: True
nedit.tabBarHideOne: True
nedit.toolTips: True
nedit.globalTabNavigate: False
nedit.lineNumbers: False
nedit.pathInWindowsMenu: True
nedit.warnFileMods: True
nedit.warnRealFileMods: True
nedit.warnExit: True
nedit.searchMethod: Literal
nedit.textRows: 24
nedit.textCols: 80
nedit.tabDistance: 8
nedit.emulateTabs: 0
nedit.insertTabs: True
nedit.textFont: -*-courier-medium-r-normal--*-120-*-*-*-iso8859-1
nedit.boldHighlightFont: -*-courier-bold-r-normal--*-120-*-*-*-iso8859-1
nedit.italicHighlightFont: -*-courier-medium-o-normal--*-120-*-*-*-iso8859-1
nedit.boldItalicHighlightFont: -*-courier-bold-o-normal--*-120-*-*-*-iso8859-1
nedit.textFgColor: black
nedit.textBgColor: rgb:e5/e5/e5
nedit.selectFgColor: black
nedit.selectBgColor: rgb:cc/cc/cc
nedit.hiliteFgColor: white
nedit.hiliteBgColor: red
nedit.lineNoFgColor: black
nedit.cursorFgColor: black
nedit.smartTags: True
nedit.prefFileRead: True
nedit.titleFormat: {%c} [%s] %f (%S) - %d
```

So it needs some more work for lower case and CamelCase, but it is working well enough.